# Delete lines after especific string in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Im trying to delete any string after tag in a xml file.

```
<App_Data App="MOD" Name="DestAreas" Value="-1"/> //From this

random lines
random lines1
random lines2
random lines3

//To the end of xml file
```

I was trying this:

```
(?i-s)(^.+\R){0}.*<App_Data App="MOD" Name="DestAreas" Value="-1"/>*\R(?1){63}
```

But just works in files with 63 lines but xml files doesn't have exact number of lines some have more some have less.

It works for me if the regular expresion deletes everything after the `<App_Data App="MOD" Name="DestAreas" Value="-1"/>` line.

Thx for reading

Comment: Like this? `<App_Data App="MOD" Name="DestAreas" Value="-1"/>\h*\K//[\s\S]*` https://regex101.com/r/anmeDz/1

Answer (score 0):

To match a line that contains `<App_Data App="MOD" Name="DestAreas" Value="-1"/>`, you just need to use `^.*?<App_Data App="MOD" Name="DestAreas" Value="-1"/>.*`.

To avoid getting the text into the match value, you can use `\K` right after so that the matched text is removed from the overall match memory buffer and the line is not replaced afterwards.

To match any text till the end of the file you can simply use `(?s).*`. This efficiently matches any zero or more characters as many as possible in one go, the `(?s)` inline modifier flag makes sure that any `.` to the right of the current location in the pattern (except in character classes and when escaped of course) can now match newlines.

So, you can use

```
^.*?<App_Data App="MOD" Name="DestAreas" Value="-1"/>.*\K(?s).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MxoDix/1).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To remove all immediately after the closing tag, you can forget what is matched so far with `\K` and then remove all characters after it with `[\s\S]+`

You do not need `(?i-s)` for case insensitive if you leave the checkbox "Match case" unchecked.

```
<App_Data App="MOD" Name="DestAreas" Value="-1"/>\K[\s\S]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bkYsbh/1)

[image]